# Javascript & Chart.JS & wkhtmltopdf don't render

Tags: javascript, html, flask, chart.js, wkhtmltopdf

I have an application over flask and I use chart.js and some basic js to create a report page with graphics.

But wkhtmltopdf doesn't want to present my data, my data shows in browser without any issue.
I tried to limit the dimensions of chart areas also added javascript delay renounce to animation, but no effect.

The result is only the html pieces of code.

The strange issue is that the browser shows the site perfect without any warning, but wkhtmlopdf gives:

```
Warning: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js:13 SyntaxError: Parse error
Warning: http://localhost:8069/xpf_reporting/report:72 SyntaxError: Parse error
```

The syntaxt error is on the line with `data.ForEach(lead => {`

Maybe is whtmltopdf more restrictive? Is there any charter preferably as small as possible that works better? I have to stick with wkhtmltopdf because it's a linux level but i can use my own JS easily.

For more clarification I add a few more parts of the webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Local request</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=297mm, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <style>
        .canvas {
            max-width: 297mm;
            max-height: 297mm;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            display: block;
            break-inside: avoid;
            page-break-inside: avoid;
        }
        table, th, td {
            text-align: center;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        th {
            background-color: grey;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
[.....]
<div class="canvas">
    <center>
        <h2 style="text-align: left;">PRI par IC et par etape / table</h2>
        <table width="300px">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>IC</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="icTableBody">
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td>Total:</td>
                <td id="totalSum"></td>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </center>
</div>

<div><p><br></p></div>
<div class="canvas">
    <h2 style="text-align: left;">PRI par DSP et par etape</h2>
    <canvas id="PRIParDSPEtParEtape"></canvas>
</div>
<script>

<script type="text/javascript">
            "use strict";
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {
                const json_data = [{"id": 19, "user": {"name": "Baubau", "name_id": 6}, "customer": "T\u00e9loise", "stage": {"stage": "First", "stage_id": 2}, "expected_revenue": 100.0, "active": true, "date": "2023-12-10 21:06:47"}, {"id": 18, "user": {"name": "Baubau", "name_id": 7}, "customer": "Besoin", "stage": {"stage": "Second", "stage_id": 3}, "expected_revenue": 300.0, "active": true, "date": "2023-12-10 21:06:50"}];
                PRIParDSPEtParEtape(json_data);
                PRIParICEtParEtape(json_data);
                createICTable(json_data);
            });
        
            function createICTable(data) {
                const icTableBody = document.getElementById('icTableBody');
                const totalSumElement = document.getElementById('totalSum');
                const icTotalSum = {};
        
                data.forEach(lead => {
                    const icName = lead.user.name;
                    const expectedRevenue = lead.expected_revenue;
                    if (!icTotalSum[icName]) {
                        icTotalSum[icName] = 0
                    }
                    icTotalSum[icName] += expectedRevenue;
                });
        
                let totalSum = 0;
        
                Object.keys(icTotalSum).forEach(icName => {
                    const row = document.createElement('tr');
                    const icCell = document.createElement('td');
                    const totalCell = document.createElement('td');
                    icCell.textContent = icName;
                    totalCell.textContent = icTotalSum[icName].toLocaleString('fr', {useGrouping: true});
                    row.append(icCell);
                    row.append(totalCell);
                    icTableBody.appendChild(row);
                    totalSum += icTotalSum[icName];
                });
        
                totalSumElement.textContent = totalSum.toLocaleString('fr', {useGrouping: true})
            }
        
            function PRIParICEtParEtape(data) {
                const userStageSum = {};
        
                data.forEach(lead => {
                    const userName = lead.user.name;
                    const stage = lead.stage.stage;
                    const expectedRevenue = lead.expected_revenue;
        
                    if (!userStageSum[userName]) {
                        userStageSum[userName] = {};
                    }
        
                    if (!userStageSum[userName][stage]) {
                        userStageSum[userName][stage] = 0;
                    }
        
                    userStageSum[userName][stage] += expectedRevenue;
                });
        
                const ctx = document.getElementById('PRIParICEtParEtape').getContext('2d');
                const userNames = Object.keys(userStageSum);
                const stages = [...new Set(data.map(lead => lead.stage.stage))];
        
                const datasets = stages.map(stage => ({
                    label: stage,
                    data: userNames.map(userName => userStageSum[userName][stage] || 0),
                    borderWidth: 1
                }));
        
                new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: {
                        labels: userNames,
                        datasets: datasets
                    },
                    options: {
                        animation: false,
                        scales: {
                            x: {
                                type: 'category',
                                stacked: true,
                                ticks: {
                                    color: 'black',
                                    order: []
                                }
                            },
                            y: {
                                stacked: true,
                                beginAtZero: true,
                                ticks: {}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        [...........]
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For our project we quickly abandoned `wkhtmltopdf` because of coming upon limitations with regard to rendering modern html/css/js, e.g. CSS3 is not supported. I don't know who would still consider this library for anything beyond plain text. Our sights are set on Puppeteer, Playwright, etc.

Comment: @Kalnode problably you are right but I'm working over a framework that is using wkhtmltopdf to parse their contant to save data in pdf. They have the problem that I can't make graph reports and when i overcome that, i couldn't save to pdf. :) . I tried the ugly way, install chrome and make the subprocess from their code, but it seems that is not feasible just to subprocess call chromium instead of wkhtmltopdf because it returns an error. :(